# Failed to inject EntityManager in websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, websphere, openjpa

I'm trying to inject EntityManager with @PersistenceContext annotations to my EJB but i keep getting NULL EntityManager

What am I doing wrong?

- server: websphere 7.0.0.0
- provider: openjpa
- ejb: 2.0

Calling to ejb from struts action

This my code: (the problem is in class TaPaymentInfoBean.java in the bootom of my post)

**persistence.xml:**

```xml
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

        <persistence-unit name="BookingUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

            <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/payment</jta-data-source>
            <class>dataobjects.PaymentInfo</class>
            <class>dataobjects.PaymentRequest</class>
            <class>dataobjects.Address</class>
            <properties>
              <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Runtime=TRACE, Tool=TRACE, SQL=TRACE"/>
              <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
            </properties>
            <
        </persistence-unit>
       </persistence>
```

**War side:**

**EJBdelegate.java**

```java
public PaymentInfoContainer getAllPaymentInfo(PaymentInfoSearch paymentInfoSearch) throws RemoteException, SQLException {
        try {   
                ParamLookupManagerHome paramLookupHome = (ParamLookupManagerHome) EJBHomeFactory.getInstance().lookupHome("java:comp/env/paramLookupManagerNEWADMIN", ParamLookupManagerHome.class, true);
                ParamLookupManager param = paramLookupHome.create();            
                return param.getAllPaymentInfo(paymentInfoSearch);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
    }
```

**EJB side:**

**ejb-jar.xml:**

```xml
<session id="ParamLookupManager">
            <ejb-name>ParamLookupManager</ejb-name>
            <home>beans.ParamLookupManagerHome</home>
            <remote>beans.ParamLookupManager</remote>
            <ejb-class>beans.ParamLookupManagerBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

<ejb-ref id="EjbRef_1111111111">
                <ejb-ref-name>ejb/TaPaymentInfo</ejb-ref-name>
                <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
                <home>beans.TaPaymentInfoHome</home>
                <remote>beans.TaPaymentInfo</remote>
                <ejb-link>TaPaymentInfo</ejb-link>
</ejb-ref>
</session>

<session id="TaPaymentInfo">
            <ejb-name>TaPaymentInfo</ejb-name>
            <home>beans.TaPaymentInfoHome</home>
            <remote>beans.TaPaymentInfo</remote>
            <ejb-class>beans.TaPaymentInfoBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        </session>
        <assembly-descriptor>
        <container-transaction>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>TaPaymentInfo</ejb-name>
                <method-intf>Remote</method-intf>
                <method-name>*</method-name>
            </method>
            <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>
    </assembly-descriptor>
```

**ParamLookupManager.java:**

```java
 public interface ParamLookupManager extends javax.ejb.EJBObject {

    public PaymentInfoContainer getAllPaymentInfo(PaymentInfoSearch paymentInfoSearch)   throws RemoteException, SQLException;

}
```

**ParamLookupManagerHome.java:**

```java
public interface ParamLookupManagerHome extends javax.ejb.EJBHome {
    public beans.ParamLookupManager create()
        throws javax.ejb.CreateException, java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

**ParamLookupManagerBean.java:**

```java
public class ParamLookupManagerBean implements javax.ejb.SessionBean {
        public PaymentInfoContainer getAllPaymentInfo(PaymentInfoSearch paymentInfoSearch) throws SQLException {
                    TaPaymentInfoHome taPaymentInfoHome = (TaPaymentInfoHome)TAHomeFactory.getInstance().getEJBHome(TAHomeFactory.TAPAYMENTINFO_HOME_NAME);
                    TaPaymentInfo taPaymentInfo = taPaymentInfoHome.create();
                    PaymentInfoContainer lst = taPaymentInfo.getAllPaymentInfo(paymentInfoSearch);
                    return lst;
            }
    }
```

**TaPaymentInfo.java:**

```java
 public interface TaPaymentInfo extends javax.ejb.EJBObject {
        public PaymentInfoContainer getAllPaymentInfo(PaymentInfoSearch paymentInfoSearch) throws RemoteException;
    }
```

**TaPaymentInfoHome.java:**

```java
public interface TaPaymentInfoHome extends javax.ejb.EJBHome {
    public beans.TaPaymentInfo create()
        throws javax.ejb.CreateException, java.rmi.RemoteException;
    }
```

**TaPaymentInfoBean:(where EntityManager is null)**

```
public class TaPaymentInfoBean implements javax.ejb.SessionBean {
 @PersistenceContext(unitName="BookingUnit")
 private EntityManager em;
}

public PaymentInfoContainer getAllPaymentInfo(PaymentInfoSearch paymentInfoSearch){
    em.find(PaymentInfo.class, paymentInfoSearch.getKey);
}
```

My server log looks just fine with no error and when I try this code it works just fine

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BookingUnit");
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

But the injection needs to work too.

Comment: Have you included the JPA API in your application? What does PersistenceContext.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() print in your application (before the NPE)?

Comment: this what i get for PersistenceContext.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() = file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/javax.j2ee.persistence.jar and yes it's came with webshpire and if i try to create EntityManager with  EntityManagerFactory it's work so i guess it's included

Comment: Ok, good. Ah, I overlooked that you were using 2.0; I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Injection and persistence-context-ref are not supported in `<ejb-jar version="2.0">`.  Try using 3.0 with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ejb-jar
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
>
  <enterprise-beans>
    ...
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: where i can see the injection minimum system requirements? i didn't see it anywhere...

Comment: I couldn't find a good reference in the EJB 3.0 specification (as implemented by WAS 7.0), but the EJB 3.1 specification is clear in table 25 that annotations are only supported in 3.0+ modules. Since annotations aren't supported in pre-3.0 modules and the `<injection-target>` element doesn't exist in pre-3.0 XSD/DTD, the result is that it's not possible to perform injection in pre-3.0 modules.